# Include PHP variable in Contact Form 7 field

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

I have used Contact Form 7 to a create contact form for a WordPress website. One of the fields is called Subject and has an ID of `#subject_field`

In my PHP file I have a variable `$reference` which generates a unique code which I would like to be the placeholder text for my subject field.

How can I implement this variable into my contact form?

I have tried using this method of placing this code in my php file but am having no luck.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 <?php   
  $('subject_field').val('$reference');
 ?>
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should insert the value as long as `$reference` is defined and this js is included on the same page as the form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#subject_field').val('<?php echo $reference; ?>');
});
</script>
```